# Use split for define a list of words

Tags: python, list, syntax

Can I use this method?

```
fields = 'id name legal_address inn'.split()
```

I think it looks more clear than:

```
fields = ['id', 'name', 'legal_address', 'inn']
```

Comment: What do you mean by the 'surest'?

Comment: the first line of code you have produces the last line as a result. The last line is the only line in each a `list` appears. The second one is a lazy way to define a `tuple` which causes confusion and finally the 3rd one is the proper way to define a `tuple`. So the only question that makes sense to me is "list or tuple for my strings?" to which the answer would be "it depends on what you want to do with it". Tuples are immutable, lists are not.

Comment: Recommend you take a quick read of the [Python Tutorial on Lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) and [5.1 More on Lists .. 5.3 5.3. Tuples and Sequences](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: Let's stop being unfriendly to the new user and stop downvoting, when I first learned Python I didn't recognize the syntax difference between list and tuple. It was all new to each of us the first time.

Answer (score 0):

A list of words:

```
fields = ['id', 'name', 'legal_address', 'inn']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the 'surest':

```
fields = ['id', 'name', 'legal_address', 'inn']
```

This creates a list and results to first one:

```
fields = 'id name legal_address inn'.split()
```

This is a expressionless tuple:

```
fields = 'id', 'name', 'legal_address', 'inn'
```

This one is a tuple that is enclosed in parentheses:

```
fields = ('id', 'name', 'legal_address', 'inn')
```

Answer (score 0):

As @EvKounis said, #1 and #4 both create a **list**, #1 by splitting the string, whereas #4 by directly instantiating the list:

```
fields = 'id name legal_address inn'.split()   # 1
fields = ['id', 'name', 'legal_address', 'inn']  # 4
```

whereas these two create **tuples**:

```
fields = 'id', 'name', 'legal_address', 'inn'  # 2
fields = ('id', 'name', 'legal_address', 'inn')  # 3
```

(A tuple can't be modified, it's "immutable". It's another Sequence type along with List. Recommend you take a quick read of the [Python Tutorial on Lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) and [5.1 More on Lists .. 5.3 5.3. Tuples and Sequences](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html))

(Occasionally you might see another synonym for creating a list, using the `list(...)` keyword; this is essentially identical to instantiating it using `[...]` as in #4 . Generally we would do #4 instead:

```
fields = list('id', 'name', 'legal_address', 'inn') # call this #4b
```

As to which one is the "surest", both #1, #4,4b: #4,4b allows you directly define the list; #1 defines it from the string contents.